# How to output a certain piece of an array using a variable C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to have an array output a certain piece of the array depending on what a randomly generated variable is.

I want to have a karate-based simulator that reads what the opponent's kick is (1, 2, 3, or 4,) and connects that with certain kicks. (Round Kick, Hook Kick, Front Kick, Side Kick) and then prints that to the screen.

Skip to int main() if you need to, the rest of the code is for reference.

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

mt19937 ranGen(time(0));
uniform_real_distribution<float> attack(0.00f, 1.00f);
uniform_real_distribution<float> defense(0.00f, 1.00f);
uniform_int_distribution<int> okick(1, 4);

string belt = "White Belt";
float landed = attack(ranGen);
float blocked = defense(ranGen);
float ekick = okick(ranGen);
int kick;
string kicks [4] = ("Round Kick","Hook Kick","Front Kick","Side Kick");

void roundKick() {
if (belt == "White Belt") {
    if (landed < 0.70) {
        cout << "Round kick to head | Blocked\n";
    } else {
        cout << "Round kick to head | Direct Hit\n";
    }
}
}

int main()
{
string yn;

syn:
cout << "Spar? y/n\n";
cin >> yn;
if (yn == "y") {
    cout << "\nFighting Stance!\n";
    Sleep(3000);
    cout << "C'ject!\n\n";
    cout << "1 - Round Kick\n2 - Hook Kick\n3 - Front Kick\n4 - Side Kick\n";
    cin >> kick;
    if (kick == 1) {
        roundKick();
    }
    cout << "Opponent used kick " << ekick;
    if (blocked < 0.50) {
        //
        //
        //I want to replace the 1 with the random Gen kick (ekick) to have the user know which kick it is
        cout << kicks[1] << " to the body | Blocked\n";
    } else 
} else if (yn == "n") {
    cout << "This is a sparring simulator, kid. Hit yes.\n\n";
    goto syn;
}

return 0;
}
```

If you don't understand just tell me what you don't and I will try to make sense of it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The ability to prepare a [minimal complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is a vital skill, much more valuable that any one coding technique or bug fix. For now, are you having trouble generating a random integer from `[1,2,3,4]`, or using an integer variable as an array index?

Comment: Basically I want to have an array and a randomly generated number between 1 and 4. That number will pick which word of the array and output it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest something like:

```
    if(blocked < 0.50) {
        ekick = okick(ranGen);   // you had this in the code, but at  a wrong place
        cout << "Replied with " << kicks[ekick] << endl; 
    }
```

The problem is that you have the parts of the statements you need in the wrong place. You have defined and initialised these global variables at the beginning of your game, so they keep the same value throughout the game.

```
float landed = attack(ranGen);  
float blocked = defense(ranGen);
float ekick;  // we have now assigned ekick within the game. So here, just declare it
```

But I suppose you start learning.  So we've solved the issue with `ekick`, but you've still a similar issue with `landed` and `blocked`. Up to you to solve it.  Senpai ni rei !

*P.S: immediately after you've done this, you should replace the horrible goto with a while loop.  And later, one nice thing to improve would be to get rid of global variables*

Comment: Thanks a lot! You didn't fix it, but I figured out how to. (Based on what you told me)